# php inserting multiple radio values with same name

Tags: php, arrays, radio-button

I'm trying to insert multiple values using radio, here is my example:

```
<input type="radio" name="toppingPrice[]" value="<?= $topping['name'];?>-<?= $topping['price'];?>">
```

this one work if I insert single input, but if I want to insert more than one for example:

```
 Size: small, medium, large <- name="toppingPrice[]" for all input values
 Cheese: yes, no <- name="toppingPrice[]" for all input values
 Level: spicy, normal <- name="toppingPrice[]" for all input values
```

this will not work because it will merge into 1 group so if I have to choose only one of all toppings.

my original code looks like:

```
foreach ($toppingPrice as $key) {
        list($toppingName,$toppingNameEn, $toppingPrice) = explode("-",$key,3);
        $tName[] =  $toppingName;
        $tNameEn[] =  $toppingNameEn;
        $tPrice += $toppingPrice;
    }
$tn = implode(",", $tName);
    $tn_en = implode(",", $tNameEn);
    $price = $price + $tPrice;
```

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="toppingPrice[]" id="<?= $topping[0];?>" value="<?= $topping['name'];?>-<?= $topping['name_en'];?>-<?= $topping['price'];?>" <? if($topping['price'] < 1){echo "checked";}?>>
```

I hope I delivered the question in the right way

please give me any idea or solution for fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use name attribute as shown in below code.

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
?>

<form name="test" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="toppingPrice.size[]" value="1"> 1
<input type="radio" name="toppingPrice.size[]" value="2"> 2
<input type="radio" name="toppingPrice.size[]" value="3"> 3

<br>

<input type="radio" name="toppingPrice.toping[]" value="4"> 4
<input type="radio" name="toppingPrice.toping[]" value="5"> 5
<input type="radio" name="toppingPrice.toping[]" value="6"> 6

<br>

<input type="radio" name="toppingPrice.level[]" value="7"> 7 
<input type="radio" name="toppingPrice.level[]" value="8"> 8
<input type="radio" name="toppingPrice.level[]" value="9"> 9

<button type="submit" value="save" /> Save
</form>
```

This will be your `$_POST` after form submit

```
Array
(
    [toppingPrice_size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [toppingPrice_toping] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
        )

    [toppingPrice_level] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
        )

)
```